# A rectangle inscribed in a semicircle

Tags: geometry

A rectangle is to be inscribed in a semicircle of radius r cm. If the height of the rectangle is h, write an expression in terms of r and h for the Area and Perimeter of the rectangle. What dimensions of the rectangle yield the maximum Area?

my attempt:

[image]

A $= 2xh$

$h = \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$

A $= 2x(\sqrt{r^2 - x^2})$

P $= 2h + 2x$

$h=\frac{p-2x}{2}$

using axis of symmetry:

$x = \frac{-b}{2a} =$?

max area $= \frac{p-2x}{2} \times \frac{-b}{2a}$

can this be solved without taking the derivative and just using optimization?

Comment: Why are you writing area in terms of $r$ and $x$? You are supposed to write in terms of $r$ and $h$. Also $P = 2h + 4x$. You have to write $x$ in terms of $r, h$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116955/maximizing-area-of-a-rectangle-inscribed-in-a-semicircle

Comment: If you already know that the largest rectangle in a circle is a square with side $\sqrt2\,r$ then you halve that to answer this question

Comment: @David see Math comment. Express A and P in terms of h. Derivative of area where h is the unknown and solve for 0. Use the h found in the equations to calculate A and P.